# Should I replace ELV 12V transformers with LED drivers?

Tags: lighting, led, junction-box, low-voltage

I have 3 pendant lights, each with its own ELV 12v transformer stuffed into its junction box, controlled by a Lutron MA-PRO dimmer that supports ELV, MLV, LED, and incandescent lighting. I would like to replace the existing 50w xenon bulbs with dimmable LED bulbs. I tried just the bulbs, but they flicker. Should I replace all of the ELV transformers with LED 12v drivers? Is it okay to stuff the transformers/drivers into the box?

Comment: What make/model is your ELV "transformer"? Have you tried with a single xenon bulb and the rest LED?

Comment: Wang House WH-801E6A-3. No, I only tried a single LED with the other 2 xenon.

Answer (score 1):

### How to apply LED lights

You should probably read [Lutron Application Note 559](https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/048559.pdf). It describes how to attach LEDs to that dimmer, and makes specific product recommendations.

[image]

[image]

They have two different groups of LED lights they recommend, depending on if you want to dim down to 20% or want even lower light.

### How to install the ELV “transformer”

Firsts, you must use a device that is approved (NEC 110.2), and that means UL-Listed (not RU-Recognized), or another equivalent “NRTL” such as ETL or CSA will suffice.  No CE, no cheap Cheese junk off Amazon.

Second, you must follow the installation instructions that come with it, since those are part of the UL listing etc.  They will tell you where you can and can’t fit it.  As long as you install it per the approved instructions, you’re golden.

LED drivers are probably not what you want, at least I don’t think they are what you think they are.  But as you see with “transformers”, it’s very common for people in LED marketing to toss around the wrong words for things.  I would build out *at least one* pendant light with exactly the products which Lutron recommends in Note 559, so if problems come up, you can narrow it down between the dimmer, “transformer” or LED.

Comment: This is the "LED Driver" that I thought should replace the existing ELV transformer: https://emeryallen.com/product/60w-transformer/

Comment: @SteveD well it doesn't look much different than the recommended ones.  It is RU Recognized which is not the same as UL Listed.  The RU means there's only one place you can mount it: in the fixture.

Comment: Assuming this company knows what they're talking about most of my questions have been answered here: https://emeryallen.com/faq/ "How do I know if I need an LED Driver with my bulbs?" Thanks for the useful advice!